# Cuk converter implementation

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I have come across this article:
https://www.powerelectronics.com/power-management/step-down-dc-dc-converter-eliminates-ferrite-cores-50khz-enabling-power-supply-chip

That describes the Cuk DC/DC converter using new GaN FETs as the best in class efficiency with tiny inductors.

- Has anyone done this in simulation?
- What controller can be used for regulating this topology?

Comment: If someone's built a controller before, then yeah, that someone has done it in simulation.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate this in LTspice, but it's slow-going. The oscillations make for a very slow simulation. Controller is an issue also; dead-time and cross-conduction are critical.

Comment: @rdtsc The models (at least those that I have seen) rely heavily on behavioural sources and behavioural capacitors, which puts a strain on the solver with the nonlinear nature of the expressions. I tried simplifying them once, managed to increase the speed (palpably, but barely), but didn't manage to reduce the switching noise and erratic behaviour for the more extreme cases. It's my impression that the SPICE world, currently, is in waiting for an intrinsic model that needs to perform, at the very least, adequately. What currently exists feels like a bad demo.

Answer (score 1):

LTSPICE works just fine for simulating the normal Cuk topology, I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work here. Just make sure you model the parasitics appropriately, the same as for any SPICE simulation.

I've personally used the LM5022 (with normal FETs) for standard Cuk, I can't see any obvious reason why it would not work on this topology either. The main switches just need a complementary waveform, so a simple inverter should suffice, and the synchronous rectifier pair will be simple too.

There are some nice single-chip high/low side drivers like the IR25604 which might help too.